# Shiro Success Redirect to a New URL

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, shiro

I am using shiro for authentication in my project

Below is the code

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                [main]
                authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
                authc.successUrl = /dashboard
                authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure
                [roles]
                ROLE_ADMIN = *
                [urls]
                /static/** = anon
                /** = authc
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now what shiro does is after authentication success it directs the user to a URL which is present in the same application ... i want to direct it to some other web application say www.facebook.com ... can anyone tell me how ??

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply let it land on a servlet that does the redirecting

```
public class RedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
        response.sendRedirect("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
}
```

Map it to the success page:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RedirectServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>packagename...RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedirectServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dashboard</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Wouter, I tried it in the way you have specified but securityShiro.xml doesnt accept servlet tag and if i put the same in web.xml its not getting redirected .. so i tried to access through HandlerInterceptor and still no success

Comment: The servlet is not being called but default shiro handler handles all requests . Say i provide www.facebook.com as redirectTo then the application is taking as http://localhost:9090/authPlat/www.facebook.com